Find the volume of the figure given below..
In the figure, the uniform cross-section PQRSTU of an open tank is formed of a rectangular part QRTU and two equal quarter circles PUQ and RTS. Given $PS= 1.6m$, $UT = 72cm.$, and the length of the tank $PV = 2m$, calculate the volume of water in cubic meters, that the tank can hold when filled to capacity (​you can use $\{\pi \approx \frac{22}{7}\}$). I tried to solve it but couldn't understand where to start and how to understand the diagram.
Image:

sorry I'm new, I don't have enough reputation to post images..

Welcome to MSE. In this forum you're expected to show some effort in order to get help. Edit your question to include your work on the problem in order to avoid your question to be downvoted and eventually closed.

@jjagmath Hi , i just dont understand how to start answering the question.., thats a huge issue for me right now

Notice that in How to ask a good question there's an specific section called Avoid "no clue" questions, which read " Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true (you may genuinely have no idea how to approach the problem), it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts. Such questions will most of the time be rejected by the community ..."

Thanks, i was new so i didnt quite know...

You can edit your question to include your thoughts on the question. It doesn't matter if they  are very basic or wrong, the point is to show that you're not just posting a problem without any efforts of your own.

sure, i will include it .

Is the tank formed by the rotation of the scheme so it has cyclical base or it is somehow a prism, I do not understand.

i feel that the base is somewhat like a quadrilateral surrounded by 4 smaller quadrilaterals whose breadth is same as the radius of 4 quarter spheres at each corner
                         |      |
                         |      |


Did you draw the picture yourself or was it given to you?

The issue is that you have a wrong picture. Your problem looks more like this:

This is the "front" view of the tank. Point $V$ is in the direction perpendicular to this figure. Think of it like coming out of the screen. Since you are given $PS$ and $UT$, you can calculate the radius $RT$. Then the volume of the rectangular portion of the tank is $RT\times QR\times PV$. Each of the quarter circles will yield a quarter of a cylinder of radius $RT$ and height $PV$. Can you take it from here?

yes, i got it .. thanks
